# how to check the path to a symbolic link, but not to what it indicates, but to the link itself. IN C

Tags: c, symlink, realpath

I've seen a lot of similar subject, I've read a lot of readlink, and realpath but problem is I need path to pliksoft, not where this link point.

for example:

> I have symbolic link: pliksoft->abc

resultat should be:

> /users/staff/trl/am/SK/pliksoft

not

> /users/staff/trl/am/SK/abc

I do it, in this way:

```
char buf[PATH_MAX], buf_2[PATH_MAX]; 

readlink(argv[1], buf, PATH_MAX); 
realpath(buf, buf_2);

printf("%s\n", buf_2);
```

but thats a bad result.

Comment: If you don't want to follow the symbolic link, why are you using `readlink`?

Comment: `readlink` is used to follow symbolic links and learn more about what they point to. If you don't care, then don't follow it, just use it as-is.

Comment: The `readlink()` function is perverse and does not null terminate the result string. The designer should be hung, drawn and quartered.  Pay attention to the return value — it tells you how long the data is.

Comment: So if i do it in this way, I have the same resultat: realpath(argv[1], buf_2)

Comment: It looks as though you need to combine the result of `getcwd()` with the value `pliksoft` to get the result you want.  I'm not sure how to generalize that though.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're trying to do:

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char buf[PATH_MAX];
        char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "foo";

        realpath(dirname(path), buf);
        printf("%s/%s -> ", buf, basename(path));
        realpath(path, buf);
        printf("%s\n", buf);

        return 0;
}
```